# Create React App (TypeScript) auto-generating react-app-env.d.ts in src directory

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

### Context:

I just ported one app from `create-react-app-typescript` to `create-react-app`. In a identically structured but different app, I did the same steps.

### Steps:

```
npm uninstall react-scripts-ts
npm install react-scripts
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

[Detailed Steps](https://vincenttunru.com/migrate-create-react-app-typescript-to-create-react-app/)

### Problems unique to second app:

- Type error: Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.  TS1208
- Generated file `src/react-app-env.d.ts`

### Assumption:

The generated file `src/react-app-env.d.ts` causes the `--isolatedModules` error.

## Actual Question:

How do I prevent `react-scripts` from generating the `src/react-app-env.d.ts` file upon `react-scripts start`?

Answer (score 5):

**Useful info:**

As expected there was an **empty file** causing an issue, but it was not the generated `src/react-app-env.d.ts` file.

**Personal context:**

An automated watch script copied an empty file into the problem project. The automated scripts never clean the destination, so the empty file hung around and later caused this issue.

### **Actual answer:**

Make sure there are no empty (.ts) files.

While this is the actual answer in the sense that it solved my problem, I still don't know why one project generates a `src/react-app-env.d.ts` file while the other does not.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in that I am moving from `create-react-app-typescript` to `create-react-app` and it's generating the file you mentioned. I don't have any empty .ts files, so I'm wondering why this is happening...

Comment: Having the same issue as @Tur1ng, no empty files.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug. React team has not yet fixed it. For now you can ignore this file by adding following inside `.gitignore`

```
/src/react-app-env.d.ts
```

For more details checkout https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6560

Comment: You should NOT add it to .gitignore.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6560#issuecomment-792323361

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted react-app-env.d.ts and I stopped getting the error.